# Hourly counting MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Since few days, I am trying to count records per hour from the MySQL database.
I have a table with a lot of records and I have column **DATE** and column **TIME** where in **DATE** I have the date of the record in the format **2022-05-19**, and in the column **TIME**, I have the time of the record in the format **14:59:38**.
What I am trying is to count every single day how many records per hour I have. Something like this:

```
DATE       HOUR     PCS
22-05-18   06-07    11
22-05-18   08-09    20
.........  .....    ..
.......    21-22    33
```

I have tried many different ways but no success.
For example:

```
SELECT 'Date', count(*) FROM `root4` 
where 
    DATE between '2022-05-01' and '2022-05-1' AND 
    TIME BETWEEN '06:11:05' AND '07:11:05'
```

Any help is highly evaluated.

Comment: It is always good if you show us your best attempt at doing this. You must have at least one after a few days effort

Comment: For advice on how to improve your question see [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) and how not to use [pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data. At the very least, please proof-read your question and fix obvious typos.

Comment: You didnt read all that suggestion :)

Comment: I placed one of the queries I used.

Comment: `HOUR 06-07` is a timespan of 2 hours not one hour, because your next record is `08-09`. So, you need to divide PCS by 2, or you need to clarify what happens to events logged in the time period `07-08` ?

Comment: You could also make sure that the code you show would actually run

Comment: [This question has a lot of what you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138479/how-to-group-data-for-every-hour-of-the-day-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not using reserved words for columns, as you will have to escape them a lot. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

If you stored `TIME` as a timestamp, you can extract the hour using the `HOUR()` function and group by that:

```
SELECT
  `DATE`, 
  HOUR(`TIME`) AS `HOUR`, 
  COUNT(1)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY 
  `DATE`, 
  HOUR(`TIME`)
```

If you happened to store it as text you can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to get the hour value from your time string.

```
SELECT
  `DATE`, 
  CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(`TIME`, '[0-9]+') AS UNSIGNED) AS `HOUR`, 
  COUNT(1)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY 
  `DATE`, 
  CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(`TIME`, '[0-9]+') AS UNSIGNED)
```

You can format your `HOUR` column how you want, like displaying `01-02` instead of `1` by using `CONCAT`, but this is your basic setup.

Comment: OP has the data stored as a timestamp, what they want is to group that data by the day/hour of the timestamp. Their desired result is shown, not the SQL definition.

Comment: I am not sure if OP has stored it as TIMESTAMP, but included both options in the answer now. Thanks!